# EOFError: EOF when reading a line only when execute it via curl

Tags: python, curl

I have a python code that construct a CURL command base on URL and data from user inputs

---

I have

```
import os

print ("______________\n")
print "   1.GET         "
print "   2.POST        "
print "   3.PUT         "
print "   4.DELETE      "
print ("______________\n")


http = int(raw_input("Select your option : "))

url = raw_input("Paste Your URL : ")

if not http:
    http = 3

if http == 1:
    cmd = 'curl '+ url
elif http == 2:
    data = raw_input("Paste Your Data : ")
    cmd = 'curl -g -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d \''+data+'\' ' + url
elif http == 3:
    data = raw_input("Paste Your JSON Data: ")
    cmd = 'curl -g -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d \''+data+'\' ' + url
else:
    cmd = 'curl -g -X DELETE ' + url

print ("_________________________________________\n")
print '\n'
print cmd
print '\n'
print ("_________________________________________\n")


run = raw_input("Do you want to run it ? [y/n]: ")
print '\n'
if run == 'y':
    os.system(cmd+'\n')
    print '\n'
else:
    os.system("clear")
    sys.exit()
```

---

## I run it

python get_curl.py

## I got

```
______________

   1.GET         
   2.POST        
   3.PUT         
   4.DELETE      
______________

Select your option : 3
Paste Your URL : http://172.19.242.32:1234/vse/vcpe/002233445567/vlan/104/device/000011223350/duration
Paste Your Data : {"acl_mode": 2, "portal_url": "http://localhost:8888/captive-portal?client_mac=$MAC&ap=$AP-MAC", "duration": 120 }
_________________________________________



curl -g -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"acl_mode": 2, "portal_url": "http://localhost:8888/captive-portal?client_mac=$MAC&ap=$AP-MAC", "duration": 120 }' http://172.19.242.32:1234/vse/vcpe/002233445567/vlan/104/device/000011223350/duration


_________________________________________

Do you want to run it ? [y/n]: y
{ "status": 201, "message": "Processed cpe HNS device duration message" }
```

---

Then, I host it on github gist, so I can share it

link =

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bheng/b23d775ee7b106cd7cc0ae5ac71b81a9/raw/c6ecd3ed7bc04699d73e1b9ed521f481ac6a41c4/get_curl.py

---

Execute the gist

```
curl "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bheng/b23d775ee7b106cd7cc0ae5ac71b81a9/raw/c6ecd3ed7bc04699d73e1b9ed521f481ac6a41c4/get_curl.py" -s -N | python
```

Result

```
______________

   1.GET         
   2.POST        
   3.PUT         
   4.DELETE      
______________

Select your option : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Why do I have different result as I would have run it on my local Mac?

How do I prevent it ?

Comment: Maybe python is getting confused with the pipe (considering that the `stdin` and causing trouble with the `raw_input`)? (so it's using the script's code as input for the script?)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're piping the `curl` command to `python`, stdin is connected to the pipe, not the user's terminal.

You can use bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) to make the curl command appear as a filename argument instead of reading it from stdin.

```
python <(curl "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bheng/b23d775ee7b106cd7cc0ae5ac71b81a9/raw/c6ecd3ed7bc04699d73e1b9ed521f481ac6a41c4/get_curl.py" -s -N)
```

Comment: Awesome suggestion!!

Comment: Works perfectly, may I ask what is this do `<( ... )` ? Also, is the command that you suggested will work on any OS ? Windows, Linux, and Mac ?

Comment: It's process substitution. I added a link to the documentation page. As it says: *Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.* It works on Linux and Macs, I don't know if it works on Windows.

Comment: For a solution that works just about anywhere, see @DavidWelch's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe is sending lines while python waits for input. Better to do something like

```
curl "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bheng/b23d775ee7b106cd7cc0ae5ac71b81a9/raw/c6ecd3ed7bc04699d73e1b9ed521f481ac6a41c4/get_curl.py" -s -N > myscript; python myscript
```